# Melhor maneira de armazenar Varchar(MAX)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, varchar

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de EAD onde trabalho.

Haverão simulados com muitas perguntas e suas respectivas respostas. Estas perguntas e algumas respostas são bem grandes geralmente e estou armazenando-as como VARCHAR(MAX) num banco SQL Server.

A tabela de simulados_perguntas tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
Cod int
Cod_simulado int
Pergunta varchar(max)
Comentario_Resposta varchar(max)
Pontos tinyint
```

A tabela de respostas é a mesma estrutura, a diferença está que ao invés de Cod_simulado está Cod_pergunta.

Entretanto, neste banco que estou trabalhando, ele possui outras tabelas não normalizadas que já possuem mais de 20 mil perguntas e para carregar esta tabela demora um bom tempo (por volta de 30 segundos) pois os valores de texto inseridos são grandes.

Por um tempo, decidiram criar varias tabelas do tipo Curso_X_Perguntas e Curso_X_Respostas onde "X" é o código do curso na tabela cursos para otimizarem o tempo de carregamento das perguntas e suas respectivas respostas. Funcionou bem, mas esta seria a melhor e a mais correta maneira possível?

Estou em dúvida em qual alternativa utilizar, pois a longo prazo eu desconheço qual ação eu deveria tomar para otimizar as futuras querys que serão executadas, a não ser por índices. Como são milhares de acessos quando os simulados são liberados, acarretará uma grande carga na tabela quando formos buscar as perguntas e respostas o que poderá gerar muita lentidão no site.

Comment: Precisa descobrir porque demora 30 segundos, o problema pode ser outro. Acho que começou ter gambiarras para resolver um problema, aí tudo fica trágico. Não sei o que responder aí. Não sei se dá para responder só com essas informações.

Comment: Entendi. Bigown, que informações vc acharia ideal eu adicionar a questão?

Comment: Sua questão está ampla e a pergunta não faz muito sentido porque não existe mais de uma forma de usar o `VarChar(Max)`. Tente caminhar no problema para identificar um gargalo específico que talvez seja o `SELECT`, a falta de um índice, um `JOIN`, etc. Não coloque a culpa no campo texto antes de analisar outros fatores porque isso pode esconder o real problema.